# Unreal Engine 4 PackageError - CompilationResultException: Error: OtherCompilationError

Tags: windows, build, unreal-engine4

So I've been working on this UE4 project using 4.23 along with Wwise 2019.1.7.

When I try to package for Windows 64-bit target I get this PackageError but it doesn't tell me what the error is (aside from ExitCode =5). It seems like an internal thing messes up in the UnrealBuildTool and I can't find the solution.

`Error log:` https://pastebin.com/zuZ2qJBP

[Output log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofbpE.png)

I was looking into the UBT code and it seems like a singleton instance is getting duplicated or something like that.

Also weirdly enough... I tested upgrading the project to 4.24 and it does compile but generates a ton of problems with Wwise and the build crashes...so I'm trying to make it work in 4.23.

Please I've been at this for over a week :(

Comment: You've gotta use the right version of Wwise & ue4. Ue 4.24 and wwise 2019.1.7. As for you runtime errors, please follow the Wwise intergration docs ( I'm not sure why but they strongly imply you should be building unreal from source ). If you're still having trouble then you can contact audio kinetic themselves and or use their forum.

Comment: hey @George! Well I was checking the Wwise documentation and it says that version 2019.1.7 should be compatible with UE 4.23. 

Well for the integration the Audio guy I'm working with told me he used the Wwise launcher to integrate it with the Unreal project. As fas I know that's the official way to do it. 

Btw what makes you say that I should build Unreal from source?